# Remove default sorting in crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, sorting, crystal-reports

I have a dataset I have created and sorted, I then bind it to a Crystal Report:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Driverperformance", con.connect)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Ecode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = Ecode
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value= fromd
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddate", SqlDbType.DateTime, 50, ParameterDirection.Input).Value= endd
 da.SelectCommand = cmd
 da.Fill(ds)
 Dim rpt As New Driverperformanc
  rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
crptdriverprfrmnc.ReportSource = rpt
```

While executing this store procedure am getting out put sorted by date..i  mean like this:

```
Ecode    Date       cntEcount    cntDelcod
E003    2013-05-05   4            3
E003    2013-05-27   0            4
E003    2013-06-01   1            2
```

but the crystal reports losing my sorting. In crystal report sorting by `cntEcount.i` getting crystal report like this:

```
Ecode    Date       cntEcount    cntDelcod
E003    2013-05-27   0            4
E003    2013-06-01   1            2
E003    2013-05-05   4            3
```

So I try to add date field to Record Sort Expert..but still am getting report sorted by `cntEcount.`

I am working on a [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) windows application..so where do I have to make a change to allow sorting by date?

Image from other question:

my " Record Sort Expert" is like this:[image]

Answer (score 2):

• Right click on group and go to "Group Expert" →
• Under "Group by" find "Options" button →
• In the "Common" tab there, change to "In original order."

Answer (score 0):

As you have groups on `CntEcode` and `Ename` Crystal will always sort by these fields first, sadly there is no easy way around this.

If you can describe what you are using the groups for there may be a work around that doesn't use groups.